# Is it possible to set Pi SSID name depending on environment (bash) variable?

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, hotspot

i would like to set up few Raspberries access points, that would have different SSIDs but would work with the same hostapd.conf files. 
For that i thought to define PI_SSID environment variable with different value for each Raspberry in bash file and use it in common hostapd.conf as SSID name.
**What i've done so far?**
In **/home/pi/.bashrc** i've added:

export PI_SSID=Razz01

In **etc/sudoers** i've added:

Defaults env_keep += "PI_SSID"

And in **hostapd.conf** i've set:

ssid=$PI_SSID

**Problem:**
After restart of Raspberry PI, its SSID name is "$PI_SSID", not "Razz01".
What i do wrong?
Is it possible at all to define raspberry SSID with environment variable? If yes how to do it?

I use Stretch raspbian.

Comment: The hostapd  isn't doing bash-shell-expansion on its config file.  You might want to edit this file before initiating the network. Consider using  `/etc/rc.local` to do something like `sed -i -s "s/^ssid=.*/ssid=$PI_SSID/" hostapd.conf` to differentiate the hostapd.conf files on startup.